# filter DataFrame using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to pandas and python.
I want to use dictionary to filter DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'e', 'c'], 'D':[0,0,0,0,0,0]})
my_filter = {'A':[3], 'B':['c']}
```

When I call

```
df[df.isin(my_filter)]
```

I get

```
     A    B   D
0  NaN  NaN NaN
1  NaN  NaN NaN
2  3.0  NaN NaN
3  3.0    c NaN
4  3.0  NaN NaN
5  3.0    c NaN
```

What I want is

```
     A    B   D
3  3.0    c   0
5  3.0    c   0
```

I dont want to add "D" in the dictionary, I want to get rows that has proper values in A and B clumns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) of `True` by columns and then compare with `2`:

```
print (df.isin(my_filter).sum(1) == 2)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
dtype: bool

print (df[df.isin(my_filter).sum(1) == 2])
   A  B  D
3  3  c  0
5  3  c  0
```

Another solution with first filter only columns with condition `A` and `B` with [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for checking both `True` by columns:

```
print (df[df[['A','B']].isin(my_filter).all(1)])
   A  B  D
3  3  c  0
5  3  c  0
```

Thank you [`MaxU`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38137821/filter-dataframe-using-dictionary/38137875#comment63706227_38137875) for more flexible solution:

```
print (df[df.isin(my_filter).sum(1) == len(my_filter.keys())])
   A  B  D
3  3  c  0
5  3  c  0
```

Comment: Yes, it means it count length of keys of dict - in this sample it is 2, because keys are `dict_keys(['A', 'B'])`.